# Prove that set $ \mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{Q}$ is countably inﬁnite by constructing a bijection from that set to the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that set $ \mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{Q}$ is countably inﬁnite by constructing a bijection from that set to the natural numbers.

It's obvious that the set is countable since it is the cartesian product of two countable sets. However, I am still confused as to how we can construct a bijection. Wouldn't it be enough to construct an injection from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

This can be done simply by constructing a set of the manner $2^k3^p5^q...$. But how would we go about defining a bijection?

Comment: "It's obvious that the set is countable since it is the cartesian product of two countable sets." How is this obvious if you don't know how to construct a bijection?

Comment: @Arthur If you know that the theorem "a cartesian product of two countable sets is countable" is true, then it is obvious, from that theorem, that $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Q$ is countable. Just because OP doesn't know how to prove the statement *by actually constructing the bijection*, it doesn't mean that the *fact* that the statement is true is not obvious.

Comment: " Wouldn't it be enough to construct an injection ...?" - In general, yes. However, it seems you have been given an **explicite** task to prove it "... by constructing a bijection from that set to the natural numbers."

Comment: One general way to do it is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Comment: Many people spent many hours adding description to the tags. Please make sure to read them carefully when choosing your tags. (This is neither "proof verification" since you are not presenting any proof, nor about large cardinals which is a technical notion in set theory.)

Comment: (Also with 150 characters for a title, you should be able to do better than "Prove that a set is countable - cartesian product".)

Answer (score 1):

Take the map $\left(m,\dfrac pq\right)\rightarrow (m,p,q) \quad p,q,m\in\mathbb{Z}\:$ 
i.e. mapping $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Assuming you know finite (countable as well) union of countable sets is countable, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: every natural can be expressed as $2^{n-1}m$, with $n, m ≥ 1$, where $m$ is odd. Try to construct a bijection $f: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ thinking about that.

Alternatively, the result that given a injection from $A$ to $B$ and another one from $B$ to $A$ there exists a bijection between the two sets is the content of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.